# python and Oracle

Tags: python, django, oracle

I would like to be able to connect to Oracle 10.1.0.2.0 (which is installed on different machine) via python.

My comp is running on Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty with Python 2.6 installed.

I have downloaded and unpacked `instantclient-basic-linux32-10.1.0.5-20060511.zip` , set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `ORACLE_HOME` to point to the directory where I unpacked it.
Then I've downloaded `cx_Oracle-5.0.2-10g-py26-1.i386.rpm` and installed it:

```
$sudo alien -i cx_Oracle-5.0.2-10g-py26-1.i386.rpm
```

When I run

```
$python -c 'import cx_Oracle'
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.6/cx_Oracle.so: undefined symbol: OCIClientVersion
```

Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is Oracle installed?  When you run SQLPlus, what happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe OCIClientVersion requires Oracle 10g release 2, but you're using release 1.

It looks like cx_Oracle binary you downloaded has been compiled with -DORACLE_10GR2 which makes it include the OCIClientVersion call. Since this is a compile-time-only option there should really be downloads for 10g and 10gR2 separately, but it would seem there aren't:

```
This module has been built with Oracle 9.2.0, 10.2.0, 11.1.0 on Linux
```

So you may have to download the cx_Oracle sources and build them yourself. (Consequently you'll need the Python and Oracle client headers.)

Alternatively you could try the cx_Oracle build for Oracle 9i instead. This sounds a bit dodgy but is apparently supposed to work.

Comment: Agreed - and I would expect the Oracle 9i build of cx_Oracle to work quite well with any 10g database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I tried building cx_Oracle 5.0.2, but received error
Connection.c:36: error: 'OCI_ATTR_CURRENT_SCHEMA' undeclared here
The piece of code in Connection.c looks like this
...
#ifdef ORACLE_10G
...
static ub4 gc_ClientInfoAttribute = OCI_ATTR_CLIENT_INFO;
static ub4 gc_CurrentSchemaAttribute = OCI_ATTR_CURRENT_SCHEMA;
#endif
...

Tried search in Oracle InstantClient SDK directory, but couldn't find OCI_ATTR_CURRENT_SCHEMA at all.

Regarding the other way, I cannot find Oracle 9i InstantClient to download.

Comment: Ugh. `OCI_ATTR_CURRENT_SCHEMA` is 10gR2-specific too. So I guess cx_Oracle isn't really designed for 10gR1 at all. You could try removing the line referencing `OCI_ATTR_CURRENT_SCHEMA` from Connection.c and the later `current_schema` which seems to be the only thing referencing it, but there may well be other problems. It's looking like the cx_Oracle for 9i will indeed be your best bet. I see a few mentions that the 9i cx_Oracle should work with the 10g instant_client, if you can't find a 9i one... Jeffrey, is that accurate?

Comment: I've installed cx_Oracle 4.4.1 for Oracle 9i and used InstantClient for 10g. It works. Actually, my goal is to use Django with my Oracle 10.1 database. Hopefully I am not going to experience any odd behaviour.
On one forum, I got interesting proposition to use InstantClient for 10gR2. Then I would be able to use cx_Oracle 5.0.2. Do you think that this is better solution? Has anybody done this?

Comment: I think it should work... to check for sure see the compatibility table at http://metalink.oracle.com/metalink/plsql/ml2_documents.showDocument?p_database_id=NOT&p_id=207303.1 however I can't get the god-awful My Oracle Support system to work at the moment as their server appears to be considerably less than ‘unbreakable’. Notes on Django and Oracle: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/ — note the data layer will try to hide the whole “empty string is null” problem from you, but it will still be lurking in there to break your webapp!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to bobince for his answer, I will just try to summarize possible solutions to make it more readable for the others.

Both `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `ORACLE_HOME` need to point to directory where Oracle InstantClient is unpacked.

- You can use `cx_Oracle 4.4.1 for Oracle 9i` together with `Oracle InstantClient 10.1`

After installing cx_Oracle 4.4.1

```
sudo alien -i cx_Oracle-4.4.1-9i-py26-1.i386.rpm
```

cx_Oracle.so is placed in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages, so following symbolic link needs to be created

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so /usr/lib/python2.6
```

Also since you are using cx_Oracle for Oracle 9i you need to create symbolic link in the InstantClient directory

```
sudo ln -s libclntsh.so.10.1 libclntsh.so.9.0
```

- Alternatively you can use `cx_Oracle 5.0.2 for Oracle 10g` with `Oracle InstantClient 10.2`

Installation procedure is similar.

```
sudo alien -i cx_Oracle-5.0.2-10g-py26-1.i386.rpm
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so /usr/lib/python2.6
```

- *Building cx_Oracle 10g sources to work with Oracle InstantClient 10.1 is not an option since cx_Oracle 10g uses code specific to Oracle 10g Release 2.*

Note: It is hard to predict whether these solutions work without any flaws (further testing is needed).